# Encrypting JWT security token supported algorithms

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, encryption-symmetric, netcoreapp2.1

I'm trying to sign and encode my JWt with this snippet:

```
var claims = new Claim[] { new SomeClaimes() };
var scKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SOME KEY");
var ecKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SOME OTHER KEY");
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            scKey),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512),
    EncryptingCredentials = new EncryptingCredentials(
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            ecKey),
            // I tryied all possible combination of algorithms here:
            SecurityAlgorithms.XXXX,
            SecurityAlgorithms.YYYY), 
    Issuer = "My Jwt Issuer",
    Audience = "My Jwt Audience",
    IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
};
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);
var jwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

But when I run the code, I get error:

> Encryption failed. No support for: Algorithm: '{0}', SecurityKey: '{1}'.

Which `{0}` and `{1}` are any combination of `XXXX` and `YYYY` in the code above (yes, I wrote a reflection snippet and have tried all possible combination of them). Which are supported algorithms for encoding (and decoding) a signed JWT?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:

```
var claims = new Claim[] { new SomeClaimes() };
var scKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SOME KEY");
var ecKeyTemp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SOME OTHER KEY");

// Note that the ecKey should have 256 / 8 length:
byte[] ecKey = new byte[256 / 8];
Array.Copy(ecKeyTemp, ecKey, 256 / 8);

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            scKey),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512),
    EncryptingCredentials = new EncryptingCredentials(
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            ecKey),
            SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256KW,
            SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512), 
    Issuer = "My Jwt Issuer",
    Audience = "My Jwt Audience",
    IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
};
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);
var jwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

As you ca see, using `SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256KW` as the *key encryption algorithm* and `SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512` as the *encryption algorithm* will do the job. Note that the key used to encryption algorithm should have `256 / 8` length.

Answer (score -2):

HmacSha512 use just one key to sign or verify token, try algorithm like RsaSha256 to public / private key encryption.

Comment: Could you please be more detailed in your answer? Perhaps append some code sample?

Comment: The question is not about having one or more keys. Please read the question again.

Comment: i am not c# specialist but HmacSha512 is not SymetricSecurityKey try new ASymmetricSecurityKey or something like that